# is there a way i can detect if someone is using any tool to detect my SAML request?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

is there a way i can detect if someone is intercepting My SAML request to Decode SAML authentication requests and later manipulate it to gain access?

Comment: Decode requests? Do you mean responses or requests? Could you be more specific in terms of actual saml2 flow?

Comment: i meant response.

Comment: No one should be able to alter responses as responses are **signed** by the IdP. Assuming your IdP doesn't leak their private key and your SP (the application) verifies the signature, there's no way to misuse the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Are you signing your responses or assertions? Can you be sure that your signing certificate's private key is safe?

If the answer to either of those questions is "no", then the  answer to your question is "no".